# Issue while using setInterval to loop through all h4 tags in div

Tags: javascript, jquery

For some time I have been trying to write code to loop through all h4 tags in div and display them one by one by having the first one fadeOut and the second one fadeIn. I have used the javascript setInterval and have used jQuery for DOM manipulation. Here is the jsFiddle I created.

http://jsfiddle.net/#&togetherjs=K2SeUVBftd

On the first iteration of the loop it runs fine but subsequent iterations the first h4 tag is no longer displayed. For debugging purposes I tried to display the current iteration number but I have not been able to put my finger on the bug in this code.

Comment: Well as you mentioned you're fading each one out afterwards, so what's the surprise?

Comment: If you look at it closely when the loop runs the second time and onwards the <h4>One</h4> is not longer visible rather it starts from <h4>Two</h4>

Comment: Use `$("#header h4:eq(" + iterator.toString() + ")").fadeIn` instead of `fadeOut`?